# Functional interface with varargs

Tags: java, interface, variadic-functions, functional-interface

I am trying to create a functional interface that can take a variable number of paramaters.

My interface is:

```
public interface Callback {
    void call(Object... args);
}
```

I tried giving an implementation like:

```
Callback toggleInfoPanel = () -> {
    boolean isVisible = infoPanel.isVisible();
    infoPanel.setVisible( !isVisible );
};
```

But it requires me to have one parameter. Why? I thought I am able to pass any number of arguments, so why can't I use it with no arguments then?

Comment: Inside the method the varargs argument is received as an array. That's how varargs always works. Your implementation needs to accept an array of arguments because that's what the interface says it accepts.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Your implementation right now accepts zero parameters. But the interface explicitly states to be capable of taking **any arguments**.

So your implementation has to be able to take **any arguments as well**.

---

> But it requires me to have one parameter. Why? I thought I am able to pass any number of arguments, so why can't I use it with no arguments then?

You seem to confuse your declaration of an **implementation** of said interface with the actual call site. It is correct that the method supports being called without arguments. But it also has to support being called with any other amount of arguments as well.

So while it is perfectly fine to **call** it with no arguments like

```
toggleInfoPanel.call();
```

it also has to be able to **support** being called with a **different set of arguments** like

```
toggleInfoPanel("hello", 2);
```

---

### Solution

You have to take an `Object[]` in your lambda. That is because Java realizes variadics with **implicit arrays**. So `Object... args` *more or less* decays to `Object[] args`.

```
Callback toggleInfoPanel = args -> {
    boolean isVisible = infoPanel.isVisible();
    infoPanel.setVisible(!isVisible);
};
```

So someone can then do

```
toggleInfoPanel.call("hello", 23, "world", "test", 2.34);
```

It is up to you whether you want to interpret `args` or not.

---

### Notes

Java already provides an interface that is capable of doing what you want, with extra type safety on top. It is called `Consumer`.

An example that would also take arbitrary inputs:

```
Consumer<Object[]> toggleInfoPanel = args -> {
    boolean isVisible = infoPanel.isVisible();
    infoPanel.setVisible(!isVisible);
};
```

and the call site:

```
Object[] args = { "hello", 23, "world", "test", 2.34 };
toggleInfoPanel.accept(args);
```

The cool thing is that this can provide type safety. Say, you want to only accept a `String`, you can do:

```
Consumer<String> printer = text -> System.out.println(text);
// or in short just: System.out::println
```

You would get compile-time safety now if you accidentally call it wrong:

```
printer.accept(5); // not a String!
```

---

On that note, there is also `Runnable` if you do not want to take any arguments and `BiConsumer` if you explicitly want to take two arguments.

For anything else, prefer wrapping your arguments into a dedicated single class instead of giving 5 arguments. So instead of:

```
Consumer<Object[]> consumer = ...
consumer.accept(new Object[] { "John", 20 });
```

Prefer creating a `Person` class and then going for `Consumer<Person>`:

```
Consumer<Person> consumer = ...
consumer.accept(new Person("John", 20));
```